# Could get the link in selenium using href attribute

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

I tried following to get the link on Start Onboarding but could not.

```
//string webElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/div/a")).GetAttribute("href");
var tes = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"/html/body/div/div/div/a")).GetAttribute("href");
var web2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//a[contains('saa',@href)"));
var web3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//a[text()='saa')]/@href"));
var tes2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//a[text()='saa')]/@href")).GetAttribute("href");
```

Start Onboarding

[image: I need to click on Onboarding which point to the link as shown in href in above html code.]

Please suggest me, where I fail and what I can do. I am new to selenium. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your html code as well as error stack trace ?

Comment: You need to give more details, what happened when you tried it? you should also post the html and error/exception message.

Comment: @Adhikari, Use of relative path for such a tag is  a very bad approach, try to use suggested once in order with id , name , class , then relative path with some tag with id

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to stay away from xpaths as they are rigid and do not work across all browsers. The below would be better.

```
var tes2 = driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector("a#idOfElement")).getAttribute("href");
```

or

```
  var tes2 = driver.FindElement(By.cssSelector("a.classnameOfElement")).getAttribute("href");
```